# Grails: How to override generated service method?

Tags: grails

Grails novice here.  I would like to override the get() and list() methods of the generated service shown here.

```
@Service(PlayerFile)
interface PlayerFileService {
    PlayerFile get(Serializable id)
    List<PlayerFile> list(Map args)
    Long count()
    void delete(Serializable id)
    PlayerFile save(PlayerFile playerFile)
}
```

Why? The default service/scaffolding model shows all domain objects for the PlayerFile class.  I want to filter this so that only the objects belonging to the logged in user (i.e. the owner) are displayed.

I appreciate your recommendations on how to do this.

Here is the PlayerFile domain class

```
class PlayerFile {
    String playersJson
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static belongsTo = [owner: User]

    static constraints = {
        playersJson sqlType: 'text', nullable: false, widget: 'textarea'
        owner nullable: false, editable: false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to override the `get` method.  You probably want a new query method...

```
@Service(PlayerFile)
interface PlayerFileService {
    PlayerFile get(Serializable id)
    List<PlayerFile> list(Map args)
    Long count()
    void delete(Serializable id)
    PlayerFile save(PlayerFile playerFile)


    List<PlayerFile> findByOwner(User owner)
}
```

If you don't need the `get` method for other purposes, delete it.

**EDIT**

Addressing the comment below:

> Where do I put the code for findByOwner() shown above? It can't be
>   added to an abstract interface.

I don't agree with that.  It can definitely be in an abstract interface.  You could turn `PlayerFileService` into an `abstract` `class` and make `findByOwner` a concrete method, but you do not have to.  It can be an abstract method in an interface, which is the common thing in a GORM Data Service like this.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/rock298query.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/rock298query/blob/3eb713a5ac2692be1fd9666eb7e6b26c8c9a0921/grails-app/services/rock298query/PlayerFileService.groovy

```
package rock298query

import grails.gorm.services.Service

@Service(PlayerFile)
interface PlayerFileService {
    PlayerFile get(Serializable id)
    List<PlayerFile> list(Map args)
    Long count()
    void delete(Serializable id)
    PlayerFile save(PlayerFile playerFile)

    List<PlayerFile> findByOwner(User owner)
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/rock298query/blob/3eb713a5ac2692be1fd9666eb7e6b26c8c9a0921/grails-app/init/rock298query/BootStrap.groovy

```
package rock298query

class BootStrap {

    UserService userService
    PlayerFileService playerFileService

    def init = { servletContext ->
        def jeff = userService.save('Jeff')
        def jake = userService.save('Jake')

        jeff.addToFiles(new PlayerFile(playersJson: '{"title":"Jeff File 1"'))
        jeff.addToFiles(new PlayerFile(playersJson: '{"title":"Jeff File 2"'))
        jeff.addToFiles(new PlayerFile(playersJson: '{"title":"Jeff File 3"'))

        userService.save jeff

        jake.addToFiles(new PlayerFile(playersJson: '{"title":"Jake File 1"'))
        jake.addToFiles(new PlayerFile(playersJson: '{"title":"Jake File 2"'))
        jake.addToFiles(new PlayerFile(playersJson: '{"title":"Jake File 3"'))

        userService.save jake

    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/rock298query/blob/3eb713a5ac2692be1fd9666eb7e6b26c8c9a0921/grails-app/controllers/rock298query/DemoController.groovy

```
package rock298query

class DemoController {

    PlayerFileService playerFileService
    UserService userService

    def jakeFiles() {
        def jake = userService.find('Jake')

        def files = playerFileService.findByOwner(jake)

        render files*.playersJson
    }

    def jeffFiles() {
        def jeff = userService.find('Jeff')

        def files = playerFileService.findByOwner(jeff)

        render files*.playersJson
    }
}
```

That all appears to work.

```
~ $ curl  http://localhost:8080/demo/jakeFiles
['{"title":"Jake File 1"', '{"title":"Jake File 2"', '{"title":"Jake File 3"']
~ $ 
~ $ curl  http://localhost:8080/demo/jeffFiles
['{"title":"Jeff File 1"', '{"title":"Jeff File 2"', '{"title":"Jeff File 3"']
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I want to override the list() method so that only domain objects owned by the logged in user. Or I want to add a new method with this behavior.

Comment: "Or I want to add a new method with this behavior." - That is what the `findByOwner` method in the code above does.  You have to pass the `User` as a parameter to the method.  If you want to move the logic related to getting the user into the service, you can do that too and the particulars of how to do that depend on what kind of security you are using and how you discover who the currently logged in user is.

Comment: "I want to override the list() method so that only domain objects owned by the logged in user." If you really want a no-arg method with the signature `List<PlayerFile> list()` and you want that method to return only `PlayerFile` associated with the currently logged in user, there is no way to do that.

Comment: Where do I put the code for findByOwner() shown above?  It can't be added to an abstract interface. Do I need to subclass PlayerFileService?

Comment: I learned that I had to follow Grails conventions religiously.  Can't have listByOwner(), must be findByOwner().

Also learned that I must add a line to the domain class.

        User owner // new!
Thanks Jeff for your detailed answer and all you do for open source!

Comment: "Can't have listByOwner(), must be findByOwner()" - That doesn't sound right.  I tested it and I can't reproduce that problem.  The code change at https://github.com/jeffbrown/rock298query/commit/f5f5af9a7cf18b6e99ae50577436539306a5c369 seems to work fine.